# How to check if a solution to an indefinite integral is correct using calculator?

Tags: calculus, integration

I was searching for a way to check the indefinite integration using calculator (not graphing one). I found this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDRtb5BgoMI

Does this method always work (for AP level questions)? For example this question:

[The question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4zNQ.png)

[answer choices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdXBs.png)

Plugging in the answer choices using the d/dx function didn't work here. Or am I missing something?

P.S.: I don't want manual solutions to the problem. I'm taking about the method in the video.

Comment: The "method" shown in the video is to differentiate until you find the correct derivative instead of integrating and selecting the correct antiderivative.  Obviously, it would not be the intended line of thinking in regards to your problem.

Comment: I saw this as a fast method to check if my answer is correct. In exams, I won't have time to do the integration again. I saw it as a good "shortcut". But for some reason, it didn't seem to work in questions involving log\e functions.

Comment: The intended manipulation in the question is to realize that $e^{4\log x}=e^{\log x^4}=x^4$.  Perhaps make that substitution, evaluate the integral by $u$-substitution, then perform the check you would like.